# Get checked on checkbox select from database

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

im working to edit data, and I retrieve data from the database. but when I tried to retrieve data in the form of a checkbox implementation, I experienced a loss in doing so. My checkbox can't check auto based on the data in my database.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Fasilitas: </label>
        <div class="row skin skin-flat">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <?php
                    $gfasis =  (explode(", ",$i['gedung_fasilitas']));
                        $fasi = [
                                    1=>
                                    "Catering",
                                    "Dekorasi Pelaminan",
                                    "Photo & Video Akad Resepsi",
                                    "Album Kolase",
                                    "Makeup",
                                    "Mc / Pembawa Acara",
                                    "Weeding Organizer",
                                    "Entertainment",
                                    "Pakaian Pengantin",
                                    "Ruang Full AC",
                                    "Meja VIP",
                                    "Lighting",
                                    "Lcd Proyektor",
                                    "Tari Tradisional",
                                    "Photo Both",
                                    "Seragam Keluarga",
                                    "Seragam Orang tua",
                                    "Meja Akad nikah",
                                    "Buku Tamu",
                                    "Kotak Amplop",
                                    "Box Hantaran",
                                    "Free Menginap di Hotel",
                                    "Qoori Akad / Resepsi",
                                    "Ruang Hias",
                                    "Raung Tunggu Pengantin",
                                    "Beskap Pengantin",
                                    "Rental Mobil Pengantin",
                                    "Kursi sofa",
                                    "Meja makan prasmanan",
                                    "Gazebo Pintu Masuk",
                                    "Red Carpet"
                                ];


                    for($kk=1; $kk<=11; $kk++) { 
                ?>

                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="<?= $kk; ?>" name="fasilitas[]" value="<?= $kk; ?>">
                        <label for="<?= $kk; ?>"><?= $fasi[$kk]; ?></label>
                    </fieldset>

                    <?php } ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <?php
                    for($kk=12; $kk<=21; $kk++) { 
                ?>
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="<?= $kk; ?>" name="fasilitas[]" value="<?= $kk; ?>">
                        <label for="<?= $kk; ?>"><?= $fasi[$kk]; ?></label>
                    </fieldset>
                <?php } ?>

            </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <?php
                        for($kk=22; $kk<=31; $kk++) { ?>
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="<?= $kk; ?>" name="fasilitas[]" value="<?= $kk; ?>">
                        <label for="<?= $kk; ?>"><?= $fasi[$kk]; ?></label>
                    </fieldset>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

as you can see my checkbox still 0, this must be got checked

[image]

when i add this code

```
for($kk=1; $kk<=11; $kk++) { ?>
<fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" id="<?= $kk; ?>" name="fasilitas[]" value="<?= $kk; ?>" <?php if($gfasis[$kk]==$kk){echo "checked";} else {}?>>
    <label for="<?= $kk; ?>"><?= $fasi[$kk]; ?></label>
</fieldset>
<?php } ?>
```

i got error like this

[image]

maybe someone can help me ?
i just need got check when value same like my database

my database data like this
[image]

Comment: Could you please check the file which you are including with the `require_once()` is not getting loaded and can you please elaborate more and give more code.

Comment: My index file is nothing special, even if I delete it still has no effect. there are only data sliders and products. @Hp_issei

Answer (score 0):

simple answer 
replace this line

```
<?php if($gfasis[$kk]==$kk){echo "checked";} else {}?>
```

with this code

```
 <?php if (in_array($kk, $gfasis)){  echo "checked";}?>
```

so your code will be like this

```
for($kk=1; $kk<=11; $kk++) { ?>
<fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" id="<?= $kk; ?>" name="fasilitas[]" value="<?= $kk; ?>" 
    <?php if (in_array($kk, $gfasis)) {echo "checked";} else {}?>>
    <label for="<?= $kk; ?>"><?= $fasi[$kk]; ?></label>
</fieldset>
<?php } ?>
```